# Sonatype Nexus: is it possible to add a redirect url configutaion in jetty.xml?

Tags: nexus, sonatype

Currently I have Sonatype Nexus running on Jetty server. My nexus is available at the url: `http://example.com/nexus`. Just wondering if is it possible to redirect the requests that comes to `http://example.com` to `http://example.com/nexus`?

Thank you so much for the help!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Jetty settings are controlled in the Nexus properties file:

- $NEXUS_HOME/conf/nexus.properties

Try changing the **nexus-webapp-context-path** property to "/" and restart Nexus:

```
# Jetty section
application-port=8081
application-host=0.0.0.0
nexus-webapp=${bundleBasedir}/nexus
nexus-webapp-context-path=/nexus

# Nexus section
nexus-work=${bundleBasedir}/../sonatype-work/nexus
runtime=${bundleBasedir}/nexus/WEB-INF
```

A better alternative would be to setup a reverse proxy for Nexus, using either Apache or Nginx. This avoids the need to run Nexus as root (in order to bind to port 80).

Comment: Thank you Mark.. Your alternate solution makes sense. But we don't have a web server in front of Nexus as ours is not public facing. We access Nexus through VPN.
And yes, I don't want to run Nexus as root. So changing the context path may not be ideal for us. But I noticed a example $NEXUS_HOME/bin/examples/jetty-http-redirect-to-https.xml. I thought there could be a similar solutions for URLs as well.